# Why to append blob download link to document body?

Tags: javascript, blob, blobstorage

I am trying to transform a table to a *csv* file then download it, but I faced an issue while using Blob to download the *csv* document. The code snippet I am using to download the *csv* file is:

```
    var elem = window.document.createElement('a');
    elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    elem.download = filename;        
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
    elem.click();        
    document.body.removeChild(elem);
```

The issue is that the csv file is not downloading with the name I am assigning to the file. It uses a randomly generated name and with no extension. example of the file name after being downloaded: 43af43ac-7491-44ed-a779-a6c8f1972b1a.

I was able to fix this by removing the append() remove() functions. Consequently, I have two questions:

1- Why the issue is happening, and what is the best solution?

2- Why to append *elem* to the body of the HTML? And why the code worked after removing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1- Why the issue is happening

That's a bug, that I couldn't reproduce on any browsers on macOS.

> , and what is the best solution?

The best solution is to let know your browser's vendor that they have a bug, then you can try to add a delay before calling `document.body.removeChild(elem);`, so that the (async) download can actually begin before you mess with the element.
One common practice is to wait a fair amount of time before doing this, which is also a good place to revoke the blob:// URL you did create, failing to do so will keep the Blob's data from being collected by the GC, causing a true memory leak once you remove your element and loose any track of the URL.

So that would give something like

```
elem.click();        
setTimeout( () => {
  document.body.removeChild(elem);
  URL.revokeObjectURL(elem.href);
}, 1e4); // 10s should be enough in most cases
```

> 2- Why to append elem to the body of the HTML?

Because [it used to be required](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1218456) in some browsers (Firefox < 70).

> And why the code worked after removing it?

That, only the ones that will try to fix your browser's bug will be able to tell you.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido. I am using Google chrome in its latest version. I will file a ticket for them ASAP. 

For the 10s delay, don't you think it is a lot of time to wait? 

Thanks for mentioning that "it used to be required". I spent a lot of time searching about it.